# Java JFrame painting

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, paint

I've had this problem before but I don't remember how I fixed it. I'm working on a RAT and so far it just sends the clients screen to the server. I use to be saving the images to the disk but now I'm trying to make it just display it on a JFrame. It displays the first screenshot but only the first, it doesn't paint the new ones.

Server:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Server extends JFrame {

private BufferedImage image;
private BufferedImage oldImage;

public Server() {
    setTitle("RAT");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        Server server = new Server();

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(25565);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection accepted!");

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        boolean firstConnection = true;

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        while (true) {
            if(firstConnection) {
                width = in.readShort();
                height = in.readShort();
                server.setSize(width, height);
                server.setVisible(true);
                firstConnection = false;
            }
            server.oldImage = ImageIO.read(in);
            if(server.oldImage != null) {
                server.image = server.oldImage;
            }
            server.repaint();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
}
```

Client:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 25565);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(toolkit.getScreenSize());
        out.writeShort(toolkit.getScreenSize().width);
        out.writeShort(toolkit.getScreenSize().height);

        while(true) {
            ImageIO.write(robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle), "jpg", out);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood the problem, it's the problem that you blocking the Event Dispatch Thread, by writing thingies like `Thread.sleep()` or `while(true)`, which is really not termed fit from Swing's perspective.

What you can do to sort this out :

- Bring the loop structure inside [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).
- Direct use of Code snippets like Socket `clientSocket =
  serverSocket.accept();` block the EDT, hence such thingies must be
  done either on a separate `Thread` or inside `SwingWorker`.
- The recursive calls to `repaint()` gets coalesced a quote from Filthy
  Rich Clients is as follows for justification on the said topic

---

```
It is important to note that repaint requests get “coalesced,” or combined. 
So, for example, if you request a repaint and there is already one on the 
queue that has not yet been serviced, then the second request is ignored 
because your request for a repaint will already be fulﬁlled by the earlier 
request. This behavior is particularly helpful in situations where many
repaint requests are being generated, perhaps by very different situations 
and components, and Swing should avoid processing redundant requests and 
wasting effort.
```

---

- Instead of Painting directly on top of your `JFrame`, it would be
  wise to Paint on top of `JPanel/JComponent` by overriding it's
  [paintComponent(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method.
- Recursive Paint calls can be achieved by the use of
  [paintImmediately(Rectangle rect)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) or [paintImmediately(int x, int
  y, int w, int h)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), methods.

Here is one example program for further help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PointsExample
{   
    private CustomPanel contentPane;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;

    /*
     * This is just JFrame, that we be 
     * using as the Base for our Application.
     * Though here we are calling our
     * JPanel (CustomPanel), whose
     * paintComponent(...) method, we had
     * override.
     */
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Locate Mouse Position");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new CustomPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            contentPane.set(x, y);
            x++;
            y++;
            if (x == 450)
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String\u005B\u005D args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PointsExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JComponent
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void set(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        paintImmediately(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    }   

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the initial call to paint() occurs with `image == null`.  This may not be the only problem, but it must be fixed.